# JQuery Slider with table and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html-table

I am new to jQuery. So I don't know how to perfectly fix this, but here I have a row full of images, I need to make it run in a infinite loop like a slider. Have searched many places, but had to return with disappointment. How do I make this work?

```
<table id="boxes" style="border: 1px solid #666;">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />           
           <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />   
           <img src="images/image3.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />   
           <img src="images/image4.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />   
           <img src="images/image5.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />    
           <img src="images/image6.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />   
           <img src="images/image7.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" />
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why can't you use some 3rd party plugin for it ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Show us what you have tried so far, so we don't present solutions you already tried and are not effective for you. Show us your jQuery code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for  your response, I did finally go  for a plugin, Slick.. It is just that,I am very new to this section, and it was all so much hard too understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any plugin then try this simple jQuery Slider

```
<style type="text/css">
    #boxes img {
        display: none;
    }

    #boxes .active {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>

<table id="boxes" style="border: 1px solid #666;">
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="res/i/img.jpg" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" /> <img src="res/i/revamp/ajax-loader.gif" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" /> <img src="res/i/revamp/yellowspike.gif" width="173" height="110" class="imgborder" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="res/js/rvmp_admin/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#boxes img:first").addClass('active');
        setInterval(function() {
            InitializeSlider();
        }, 3000);

        function InitializeSlider() {
            if($("#boxes img").hasClass('active')) {
                var nextImg;
                if(($("#boxes .active").index() + 1) == $("#boxes img").length) {
                    nextImg = $("#boxes img:first");
                } else {
                    nextImg = $("#boxes .active").next();
                }
                $("#boxes .active").hide("slow").removeClass("active");
                nextImg.addClass('active');
            } else {
                $("#boxes img:first").addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Cycle. It's the simpliest I know.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

I think a plugin would be a good idea. If you want the row of images to scroll like a stock ticker, you can use something like [jQuery SimpleScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/). If you want a standard slideshow you could try a lightweight image slider like [Nivo Slider](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider)

Comment: I finally went for slick after Immensive Google Search.. Its completed.. Thanks for your support